# Partial derivatives stopping me from grasping this diffusion law?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, mathematical-physics

This a diffusion law that helps understand the divergence of heat flux and temperature radiation inside the atmosphere and related to some dynamics of atmosphere physics used by Sellers (1969).

$$ F[T]=∂/∂x [(1-x^2)D* {∂T} / {∂x}] $$

where D is constant, T is the temperature and F is some operator.

I tried to study partial derivatives and how to solve them but haven't found any form like this, specially where there is another derivative inside the bracket as well..

Could you please recommend any study guides that will lead me to understand this equation ?

Looking forward and hope this is interesting for you as well, I am currently studying simple energy balance climate models regarding Solar Energy.